# angularjs application boot: making a reusable module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angularjs and developing several applications (at the same time, boss' orders).

All my applications have some common tasks related to initialization, but I don't know how to make these tasks a reusable module (yes, maybe I'm a noob). I've researched a lot, but I only got more confused. :(

Well, here is the code that I need to make reusable as an angular module. The idea is that those functions run before the application do anything.

```
/**
 * INITIALIZATION - STEP 1 - This is the entry point
 * @param {function} callback
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function runApplication(callback) {
    showLoadingBar();
    $.getJSON("myUrl").done(function (data) {
        // do stuf, with error verification, then...
        step2(callback, data);
    }).fail(function () {
        showCriticalErrorMessage("foo");
        hideLoadingBar();
    });
}

/**
 * INITIALIZATION - STEP 2
 * @param {function} callback
 * @param {object} whateverData
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function step2(callback, whateverData) {
    // do stuff with whateverData, with error verification, then...
    $.ajax({
        "url": "myOtherUrl",
        "type": "GET",
        "dataType": "json",
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }).done(function (data) {
        // do stuff with data, with error verification, then...
        step3(callback);
    }).fail(function () {
        showCriticalErrorMessage("bar");
        hideLoadingBar();
    });
}

/**
 * INITIALIZATION STEP 3
 * @param {function} callback
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function step3(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        "url": "justOtherUrl",
        "type": "GET",
        "dataType": "json",
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }).done(function (data) {
        // do stuff with data, with error verification, then...
        step4(callback);
    }).fail(function () {
        showCriticalErrorMessage("baz");
        hideLoadingBar();
    });
}

/**
 * INITIALIZATION STEP 4
 * @param {function} callback
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function step4(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        "url": "anotherUrl",
        "type": "GET",
        "dataType": "json",
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }).done(function (data) {
        callback();
        hideLoadingBar();
    }).fail(function () {
        showCriticalErrorMessage("qux");
        hideLoadingBar();
    });
}

// then i need to call step1 inside some controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use angular js Run block to kickstart application. Also Make use of angular js promises using $q service which is similar to your done and fail functions. resolve the dependencies one by one. create angular js service or factory then inject the created service/factory in main module run block then call the step1 function. In your you only needed to expose step1 method. And you can make other functions as private without exposing.

I hope below sample code will help you

```
      angular.module('service', [])
  .factory('initialize', function ($http, $q) {
    var step1 = function (url, config) {
      //$q is the angular js service to create promise
      var defer = $q.deferred
      $http.get(ur, config).
        then(function (data) {
          step2(data).then(function (data) {
            step3(data).then(function () {
              //resolve the dependency
              defer.resolve();
            }, function () {

            })
          }, function () {
            //handle error case
          })
        }, function () {
          //handle the error case
        });
      //return the promise
      return defer.promise;
    };
    var step2 = function () {
      //which basically returns the promise
      return $http.get(ur, config);
    }
    var step3 = function () {
      //which basically returns the promise
      return $http.get(ur, config);
    }
    return {
      //expose the step1 to access in controller
      step1: step1
    }
  });

//then your controller or run block

angular.module('main')
  .run(function (initialize) {
    initialize.step1(url, config).then(function () {
      //success fully bootstrapped
    }, function () {
      //Failed to Initialize
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some startup operations in "config" and "run" methods,
however, in "config" phase you may only use providers, not full service, controllers etc instances.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.run(function($rootScope) { 

  console.log("this runs after config");
});
app.config(function(){
  console.log("this runs first");
});
```

EDITED:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5nxUDkrNMpIRUaoriryn?p=preview

Comment: ok, but how do I make it reusable troughout many applications?

Comment: fixed it, now you can have universal module, that you can include in any angularjs app